# jquery assistance to get substring of ms-vb2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with a SharePoint page. I'm want to only show the date and not the time that resides in a td class ms-vb2 elements.

Here's a sample of the HTML
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx5VD.png)

```
<tr class="ms-itmhover" iid="8,__bg40001300,0" setedgeborder="true">
<td class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell">
<td class="ms-vb-title" height="100%" onmouseover="OnChildItem(this)">
<td class="ms-vb-title" height="100%" onmouseover="OnChildItem(this)">
<td class="ms-vb2">320 Western Blvd Suite 102</td>
<td class="ms-vb2">Glastonbury</td>
<td class="ms-vb2">No</td>
<td class="ms-vb2">2/5yr</td>
<td class="ms-vb2">
<nobr>7/30/2014 8:00 PM</nobr>
</td>
```

Here is a sample of the jquery script I'm trying to use but it's not working. since I have several elements using the same td class I'm trying to only select the classes that only contain 8:00 PM in their text.

```
<script src=".. .."></script>
 <script language="javascript">

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("RemoveTime");

function RemoveTime(){
 $("td.ms-vb2:contains(8:00 PM)").substr("",11);
 }</script>
```

It's not working but if I wanted to highlight all elements with the same td class and containing the 8:00 PM time I can do so with this in my above script:

```
$("td.ms-vb2:contains(8:00 PM)").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

But this is not the effect I want. I would like to just show the DD/MM/YYYY. Can someone provide some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```js
$('table td.ms-vb2').children('nobr:contains(8:00 PM)').each(function(index, element) {
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace('8:00 PM', '');
});
```

Comment: Thanks gaemaf for taking the time to help. I am new to the jquery framework and am still carrying my technical journey building proficiency in jquery. I'm still educating myself on how to chain the methods and functions to access the right selectors and elements I want to take actions on. Your answer proved to be exactly what I needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

your selector `$("td.ms-vb2:contains(8:00 PM)")` is going to select the parent div. To that you'll probably want to call `.html()` on it. That should return something like `<nobr>7/30/2014 8:00 PM</nobr>` which you'll want to run through the JavaScript string replacer.

```
var newHtml = $("td.ms-vb2:contains(8:00 PM)").html()
  .replace('/[ ]\d+:\d+[ ]\w{2}/','');

$("td.ms-vb2:contains(8:00 PM)").html(newHtml);
```

something like that. (not tested)

Comment: Thanks Iwnnay for your response. I did not try out your suggestion as I went from the top down in terms of responses to my inquiry. I will try your suggestion after the New Year activities I have planned. Thanks for your response.